# Send Notification to device tokens

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm using Cloud Functions with Cloud Messaging and I want to send a notification to all devices which have a specific userRole (see userRoleList).
Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do that.
For example, I just want to push the deviceTokens with userRole "Aktive" to the deviceTokens.

[image: Here is my structure in Cloud Firestore]

And here is my code for Cloud Functions so far:

```
exports.sendNotificationAusschuss = functions.firestore.document('news/{newsId}').onCreate(async snapshot => {
    const news = snapshot.data();
    console.log('Message received');

    //var deviceTokens = ??
    

    const payload = {
        notification:{
            title: 'Message received',
            body: `${news.newsText}`,
            sound: "default"
        }
    };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceTokens, payload);

    

    
});
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can query Firestore to retrieve the users with a given role.

```
const snap = await admin.firestore().collection('users')
  .where('userRoleList', 'array-contains', 'Aktive')
  .get();
const tokens = [];
snap.docs.forEach((doc) => {
  tokens.push(doc.data().deviceToken);
});
```

Then split `tokens` into batches of 500, and:

```
await admin.messaging().sendMulticast({
  tokens,
});
```